# Do we need the tag wiki Excerpts to start with "Questions relating to . . ."

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-wiki

Looking at [the tags page](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tags) we see that the majority of the Excerpts start with something like:

- Questions relating to
- Questions about
- Questions on
- Questions dealing with
- For questions specific to

et cetera.  Is this necessary or beneficial?  It seems to me that this could be left off of most Excerpts as it is tautological that a tag is "for questions..."

Comment: It may be tautological, but [some people do not know](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/1689/revisions) that tag wiki excerpts are _not_ meant to be wikipedia style explanations of the obvious, but rather to clarify the purpose of the tag on this site. :D ;)

Comment: @R.M but the purpose of *every* tag is "for questions..." -- how is that helpful?

Comment: I agree with MrW here, even the system removes these ...

Comment: @Szabolcs The system doesn't remove these... it only removes `<tagname>` or `<this tag is>`, etc. In fact, if anything, the system _encourages_ this style of writing, because if you write `<this tag is for questions on blah>`, all that remains is `<for questions on blah>`

Answer (score 0):

It indeed seems like it is a waste of space to repeat "Questions on...", and as far as I understand, the SE engine **should** truncate these when the excerpts are displayed in e.g. the mouseover box. On the other hand I could not come up with any good English phrase that can be used to start a sentence and does not render the excerpt to something that is barely better than a list of keywords.

Anyway, I think we should remove the redundant words, and if that is the general consensus I will slowly scan through the most used tags to do it.

Bearing in mind that the displayed excerpt is truncated and most of the time only the first ~20 words are visible, I would suggest providing only one sentence with the most barebone essentials that help delineate the usage of the tag and distinguish it from other tags.

Comment: The system does not truncate "Questions on..." You can see by hovering on any question in [tag:list-manipulation]. I'm not opposed to not starting with the same phrase, but I'd like it to be clear for others and users that excerpts (and main) are not meant to be wikipedia style, like in my example under the question above

Comment: Also see my comment to Szabolcs under the question